# How do you solve this Chrome button border bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Anyone know how to get around this problem?  I'm doing some custom button styling.  It looks fine in Firefox:

[image: Button as rendered by Firefox]

But it doesn't look right in Chrome 15.0.874.106:

[image]

The top border has some dark pixels in the center of the button.  They only show up when the button gets to be at least a certain width.

Here's the CSS:

```
.mybutton, .mybutton:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 6px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  position: relative; 
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  line-height: 1; 
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.mybutton:active { 
  top: 1px; 
}
.mybutton:hover { 
  background-color: #aaa; 
  color: #fff; 
}
```

I've searched for other mentions of this problem but so far haven't found anything.  Anyone else encounter this before?

Comment: Update to Chrome 16 and you won't encounter this problem anymore ;)

Comment: Is there a workaround for those stuck on 15?

Comment: I am using 15.0.874.106 on Mac, cannot replicate. See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kW3u4/

Comment: I'm running Windows.  Also, you're not seeing the problem because your button is too narrow.  It only shows up after the button gets wider.  When I add more text to the button, the problem shows up on your jsfiddle link.

Comment: Is the only difference it is like 1 or 2 px smaller?

Comment: @Shredder The size isn't what bothers me.  It's the dark pixels in the border on the top.

Comment: @mightybyte Ah. Well I don't see it on my Chrome (15.0.874.106 m) on windows xp using Adam's jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be this

`border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);`

that is causing the problem.

When I remove it, all is good... even with many words in the button.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kW3u4/2/

*Tested on Chrome 15.0.874.106 on Windows*

Comment: Bizarre.  I didn't even think to try removing that one since it is for the bottom border.  It does slightly change the look of the button, which I guess makes it a little less than satisfactory to the pixel perfect crowd.  But it's certainly better than the ugly top border.  Thanks.